# how to get json in url https

Tags: php, json, url, cakephp-helper

I want to get timeZoneId using googleapis url. I want this url return me json response to parse it later and insert lat and long in my database. It works fine when it's not a googlemap url but i have the famous "request_denied" error when I use this kind of url in my code:

How to get json in url from google, I want to get timezone from latitude, longitude, and timestamp

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331766000&sensor=false

I have tried get data from URL with file_get_contents.

```
$json_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331766000&sensor=false';
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->timeZoneId;
```

But it doesn't work. It alwy return **"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"** 
Thanks any got a tip.

**Update**

> thank for all :) i checked in php **extention-> php_openssl** and it
>   work

Comment: "it not work" is *never* an appropriate description of what actually happens.

Comment: It's simple, with http you are getting 'REQUEST_DENIED'.

Comment: thank for all :) i checked in php extention-> php_openssl and it work

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `s` in the url:

```
$json_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331766000&sensor=false';
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->timeZoneId;
```

This works on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $json_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331766000&sensor=false'; 

    $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    echo $data['timeZoneId'];
```

Try this i think this might help. The problem is with json_decode.

Answer (score 1):

Change your url from:

```
$json_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331766000&sensor=false';
```

to this:

```
$json_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331766000&sensor=false';
```

With **http** you are getting REQUEST_DENIED.

Comment: :( this work on pc but not work on host :(